# How to format all files under a dir in emacs?

Tags: emacs

In emacs, I format a file as:
1) C-x h (or M-x mark-whole-buffer)
2) C-M-\ (or M-x indent-region)

I need help show me how to format all files under a dir?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's another way to go about it:

First, evaluate this function definition in your `*scratch*` buffer:

```
(defun indent-marked-files ()
  (interactive)
  (dolist (file (dired-get-marked-files))
    (find-file file)
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer nil)))
```

Next, open a Dired buffer at the top level of the directory under which you want to change all of the files.  Give the dired command a numeric prefix so that it will ask for the switches to give to the `ls` command, and add the `R` (recurse) switch: <kbd>C-u C-x d R RET your-directory RET</kbd>.

Next, mark all of the regular files in the recursive directory listing: first <kbd>* /</kbd> to mark all the directories, then <kbd>* t</kbd> to toggle the selection.

Finally, run the above command: <kbd>M-x indent-marked-files</kbd>.

Be aware that if you already have any buffers visiting any of the target files, they'll be killed by `indent-marked-files`.  Also be aware that none of the file changes will be undoable; use with caution!  I tested it in a simple case and it seems to work as described, but I make no guarantees.

Comment: The solution with macros, proposed by @legoscia, is definitely simpler and more intuitive.

Answer (score 9):

Create a macro to do it.  Open the directory in dired (<kbd>C-x d</kbd>), and then:

1. Put point on the first file.
2. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to start recording the macro.
3. Hit <kbd>RET</kbd> to open the file.
4. Format it with <kbd>C-x h</kbd>, <kbd>C-M-\</kbd>.
5. Bury the buffer with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `bury-buffer`. You'll be back in the dired buffer.
6. Go down one line.
7. Hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to stop recording the macro.

So now you have a macro that opens the file on the current line, formats it, drops back to dired, and puts point to the next line.  Run it with <kbd>F4</kbd> as many times as needed.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer for its simplicity. Instead of `M-x bury-buffer`, I prefer killing it `C-x k`.

Answer (score 2):

I am late in answering this question, but this is still the first result on Google.

I made an improvement to **@Sean**'s answer to remove the need for the complicated Dired interaction.

```
(defun my/indent-files (directory extension)
    (interactive (list (read-directory-name "Directory: ")
                       (read-string "File extension: ")))
    (dolist (file (directory-files-recursively directory extension))
        (find-file file)
        (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
        (save-buffer)
        (kill-buffer nil)))
```

Sample use: `M-x my/indent-files` then `~/Dropbox` then `.org`.

This will run `indent-region` on the **all** `.org` files, save the buffer then kill it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(defun format-all-files (regexp)
  "Format multiple files in one command."
  (interactive "sFind files matching regexp (default all): ")
  (when (string= "" regexp) (setq regexp ""))
  (let ((dir (file-name-directory regexp))
        (nodir (file-name-nondirectory regexp)))
    (when dir (cd dir))
    (when (string= "" nodir) (setq nodir "."))
    (let ((files (directory-files "." t nodir nil t))
          (errors 0))
      (while (not (null files))
        (let ((filename (car files)))
          (if (file-readable-p filename)
              (progn 
                (set-buffer (find-file-noselect filename))
                (mark-whole-buffer)
                (indent-region-or-balanced-expression)
                (save-buffer)
                (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
            (incf errors))
          (setq files (cdr files))))
      (when (> errors 0)
        (message (format "%d files were unreadable." errors))))))
```

But note that this must load the file-specific mode over and over again, which may involve syntax highlighting or whatever initialization happens on a load of that type. For really big formatting jobs, a batch program such as `indent` which *only* indents will be much faster.

Comment: I suspect it won't "load the file-specific mode over and over again", and instead will work reasonably fast (not that I've actually tried it :-)

Comment: thanks, but had a error with this:
let: Wrong number of arguments: directory-files, 5